What's "further over" mean in this context
In the movie "Insomnia" by Christopher Nolan, there is a scene in which a group of townspeople enters a forest to conduct a search, in an area in which a crime was committed.
A detective who came from L.A to work on this case and a local Police Officers are coordinating the sweep.
In this scene we can see a group of townspeople entering a small wooded area and we hear the dialogue between the detective and one of the officers (dialogue below):


Police Officer :Do you think they should start further over?
Detective: No it's a waste of time. He stayed down by the water as far
as he could. I saw him over the rocks. He thought he'd lose us there.

To me as a non-native speaker the word "over" suggests that something is on the other side of something else (like the road that we can see behind the trees in the picture). But this is an American movie and very recently, (around 40 seconds ago to be precise) I learned that the phrase "in the next aisle over" meant the same thing as "in the next aisle" and not "in the next but one aisle" as I hitherto though. Is this a similar case here?
Then there's the vagueness of the words "intervening space" in the definition of the adverb "over" (everything is an intervening space unless the things are touching and even that could be disputed by some annoying particle physicists).
"over" (adverb):
on the other side of an intervening (see intervene sense 4) space
the next town over (Merriam Webster)
Also, this could not be an adverb but a preposition:
"over" (preposition):
—used as a function word to indicate position on or motion to the other side or beyond
lives over the way
fell over the edge

Someone is downvoting all my posts. I answered your question fully.

You have ignored my answser yet it is the only one that 1) defines it formally 2) contrasts it with other prepositions. You had already correctly referenced 1) here.

It's an idiomatic meaning: you can tell this because you couldn't vary the wording and keep the same meaning. You couldn't say "Do you think they should start over" or "Do you think they should start less/nearer over" with anything like the same meaning. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be an idiom that is in a dictionary.

Don't overthink!
"over" as in "over there" merely suggests a different location.  "Do you think we should start further over" is just a suggestion to search in a different place.  The place that the officer is referring too would have to be understood from context, body-language and shared knowledge.

So this would be the first "adverb" definition from my post that applies here right? It's the same "over" that is used in "it's in the next aisle over" right? Thanks

I believe that your answer is the correct one but I will put this question to a bounty so that more people confirm it as this is not so easily found in dictionaries or other resources for learning for ELLs like me.

over there is not up there. Yes, a different location but horizontally with a space between the first thing and the second.

Look no further:
The meaning of the phrase "further over" is clear from the Cambridge Dictionary definitions. So, you don't need to look further.
I. Dictionary Meaning:

further.
adverb.
comparative of far : to a greater distance or degree, or at a more advanced level:
.
over.
preposition.
over preposition (HIGHER POSITION).
above or higher than something else, sometimes so that one thing covers the other; above:

II. Explanation of the Scene:.
The phrase  "further over" in the dialogue refers to shifting or beginning a search at a location that is farther along or to the side relative to a specific point.
The policeman is asking whether the townspeople should start their search at a spot farther to one side of their current position. This might help them better cover a larger portion of the wooded area.
The detective, however, feels this is unnecessary because he believes the suspect is hiding among the rocks near the river.
Your earlier questions, such as  "bought out the house" and the use of  "over" in the movie Rear Window, had elements of wordplay or puns. In this case, however, the meaning is straightforward.
Edit - 1

"Further" and "further over" differ: Adding "over" implies lateral movement or a specific shift in position.
"Over" acts as an adverb: Modifying the direction suggested by "further."
Context matters: Similar to "in the next aisle over," it focuses on nearby adjustment rather than crossing a boundary.
In the scene: "Further over" guides the search slightly to one side, staying within the same general area.


Your question is summed up "start further over"

start further over

What you need to start? It's an "efficient" search. The time and manpower, namely resources are finite.
If you want to be efficient, where should you start a search? It should be started from where?

from the place further over (proved not efficient by the other speaker)

What is the reference point? It has two ones: the speaker and the surroundings. For example, "Come over here!": Come to me here!; "There is a bridge over the river." The reference point is me, the river. You should consider two variables when you interpret "further over".
The word 'over' has basic concept: separated vertically or horizontally right/directly from the reference point: over the river (vertically), bend over (vertically towards horizontally), come over(horizontally, across)
The 'over' in your example has reference point(horizontally/across); they are not describing 'something over something' but describing 'whether from here or from "further over (there)"'
speaker's location->-here--further here[=there]--further there[=over there]--further over (there)
You should keep in mind that 'over' means vertically and separatedly and right/directly positioned from the reference point[ex) over the head, fly over (our head)] or horizontally[ex) cross over]
In your example 'start a search further over', the 'over' means, to put it simple, 'start a search from over there (in terms of the shared view point)'

further over
further down
further along
further up
further in
further out
[Well, that's probably most of them]
etc.
Merriam Webster
over
: on the other side of an intervening space
the next town over
Also, over suggests horizontality, not verticality.
To start further over. is locative and adverbial.
